# How to fix this issue, when local account has been changed from your sql server and thrown file path be changed?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I have this error, on my project folder i have created _AppStart.mdf while the account on SQL Server from the Administration Service changed to local account on sql server. Now i am getting this exception each time i am trying to create new users to my database. What can i do to resolve this issue?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            user.Email = model.Email;
            user.ConfirmedEmail = false;
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); ?/** This throws an error line 88, each time new user is created. **/
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                    new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ggcobani@gmail.com", "Web Registration"),
                    new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(user.Email));
                m.Subject = "Email confirmation";
                m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Thank you for your registration, please click on the below link to complete your registration: <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">{1}</a>", user.UserName, Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Token = user.Id, Email = user.Email }, Request.Url.Scheme));
                m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mydomain.com");
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ggcobani@gmail.com", "password");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(m);
                return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account", new { Email = user.Email });
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Images of errors really don't help us help you. Please paste the error into your question in a quote block. Don't forget to include your code, and *all* the related errors.

Comment: That code doesn't have anything to do with creating a database, that I can see. And you *still* have an image in your question of an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name = "eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistration; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

1. The issue was file was existing on the project folder. Under _AppStart.mdf
2. Re changed my connectionString as shown, the error is gone although its throwing a new one due to connected party.